# change inner html using Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with "tokens" (characters). I would like to move the tokens from one `td` to another, if the `td`'s `span` is empty.

In the first step when I click on the `td` with content in it, I highlight the `td`

In the next step when I click on the `td` where I want the token to move, I add the token to this `td`'s `span`'s inner HTML and empty the previously clicked `td`'s `span`'s children.

Simple enough. The JSFiddle is what I came up with, I thought, would work, but it does not.

https://jsfiddle.net/abyu3sg9/5/

The code executes, but the `innerHTML` in the `spans` don't change.

I don't understand why not.

Comment: whoever downvoted, have the curtsey to atleast leave a comment as to why you downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you try to set the value here:

```
$($(this).html()).html(lastclickedcontent);
```

$(this).html() returns a string, which in the case of the second box will be:

```
<span></span>
```

Calling $("some html"), which you are doing with the outer $(), creates a new DOM object with the content "some html".  Then you are setting the HTML of that new DOM object to x", when you really want to be setting the value of the span inside the TD that was clicked (which is $(this)).

I made a couple of small changes to your fiddle and the sample below works:

```
var lastclicked = null;
var lastclickedcontent = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickme").click(function (event) {
        var tilecontent = $(this).children('span')[0].innerHTML;
        if (tilecontent.length > 0) {
            $(this).css('background', 'lightgreen');
            lastclicked = $(this);
            lastclickedcontent = tilecontent;
            $('p').html("GREAT! now click on the empty cell!");
        } else {
            if (lastclicked !== null) {
                $(this).children('span')[0].innerHTML = lastclickedcontent;
                //$($(this).html()).html(lastclickedcontent);
                $(lastclicked).children('span')[0].innerHTML = '';
                lastclicked.removeAttr('style');
                $('p').html("Awesome! Your token should have moved!");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/Lo9fdL1s/

Comment: now why didn't i think of that. nice. thanks. but any ideas as to why `$.html()` did not work ?

Comment: $($(this).html()).html(lastclickedcontent) first gets the html as a string ("<span>x</span>"), then you're basically calling .html on that string.  $("<span>x</span>").html() will return "<span>x</span>", where you wanted "x".

Comment: no, i don't think so, i am able to get the innerHTML this way `$($.html()).html()` ... only not able to set it for some reason. see https://jsfiddle.net/abyu3sg9/12/ ... lines `5-8` in JS window

Comment: When you do $($(this).html()).html() you are not getting the HTML of the object you think you are.  The inner $(this).html() gives you a string equal to "<span>x</span>".  Wrapping that string with $(...) creates a new DOM object with that content.  Then calling .html() on that new object gives you "x" because that's the content you used to create the new object.  Setting it will work, but it's not the same dom object that is visible in the HTML - it is a new temporary one that is not displayed yet.

Comment: For fun, I added a bit of JS to your original fiddle to show you what I mean.  You'll see that when you click the second box, you are indeed adding the value 'x' to a brand new DOM object as opposed to the box being clicked.  I then append the new DOM object to a test div where you can see the value was properly set on the new, temporary object.
https://jsfiddle.net/abyu3sg9/5/

Comment: i think you pasted the wrong fiddle link. you pasted my original fiddle again.

Comment: Oops!  Correct "for fun" fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/8r6zeqe8/
Every time you click the second box, you are re-appending the contents of the new DOM object to the "test" div.

Answer (score 0):

Since I got more clarification on what you were trying to do, you shouldn't be using html at all. You should be looking for **Children** elements. Change this:

```
$($(this).html()).html(lastclickedcontent);
```

To this:

```
$(this).children("span")[0].innerHTML=lastclickedcontent;
```

Comment: I don't want to loose the `span` the `$(this).html()` is the `td` of class `clickme` and `$($(this).html()).html()` is the `span` within it. I want to change the innerHTML of `span` not the `td`.

Comment: see the revised answer

Comment: so, `$($.html()).html()`even though can be used to get the inner html, can't be used to set it ? honest question, why was this design decision taken ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `localStorage` for this, here is a [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/abyu3sg9/13/)

BTW, this method preserves your `span`s and it lets you move the token between multiple `td`s

```
localStorage.removeItem("lastclickedIndex");
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(event){
        if(localStorage.getItem("lastclickedIndex") !== null && $(this).find('span').html()==''){
            var last = localStorage.getItem("lastclickedIndex");
            $(this).find('span').html( $(".clickme").eq(last).find('span').html());
            $(".clickme").eq(last).removeClass('lgrn');
            $(".clickme").eq(last).find('span').html('');
            $(this).addClass('lgrn');
            localStorage.removeItem("lastclickedIndex");
        }
        else if($(this).find('span').html()!=''){
            localStorage.setItem( "lastclickedIndex", $(".clickme").index( $(this) ) );
            $('clickme').removeClass('lgrn');
            $(this).addClass('lgrn');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If the downvote was for the broken fiddle, I've updated with the correct link : )

Comment: this works, and it's a pure jquery way of doing this, though, feels convoluded and more complicated than the hacky JS, JQuery mixed solutions others have proposed. but any specific reason why you recommend localstorage for such a trival thing ? seems like overkill to me. btw, i didn't downvote you :)

Comment: @anu IMHO it's just cleaner than having a global variable floating around

Comment: ah, okay, i would'nt leave that variable floating around in global scope. i'd put it in a closure in my real implementation. thanks for the advice. i agree that globals are bad idea. btw updated my comment, please review.